# Se puede correr una aplicación de windows form en mac os

Tags: c#, .net, macos

Buen día

Actualmente tengo una aplicación de windows form en .NET Core 3.1.
Quiero que esta corra tanto en Windows como en Mac OS

de que manera la puedo compilar para que corra en ambas plataformas?

Comment: Si es una aplicación de escritorio (Forms, Wpf...) no es compatible con mac por el momento. Segun parece, [MAUI](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui) (que acaba de salir con Net 6, y es una evolución de Xamarin) permite aplicaciones de escritorio en mac

Comment: gracias, voy investigar para ver si me funciona